# Table is not resizing to fit inside div

Tags: html, css

Designing a html website for uni, must have one or more tables, very new to using using html and css so please forgive me D:

Wanted a semi-opaque box to put things like text, headings, tables etc. in that would resize with the page, with the contents still fitting. Have used divs to do this.

Problem is, table will not resize to fit within the box or even the page. 

Here is the box's css:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(229, 191, 180, 0.7);
    border: 0.5px solid #93586a;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Here is the table's css

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
    color: #93586a;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}

th {
    border: 0.5px solid #93586a;
    background-color: E1AEA4;
    text-align: center;
    color: #93586a;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px;
}

td {
    border: 0.5px solid #93586a;
    background-color: #E7BEB6;
    text-align: left;
    color: #93586a;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    padding: 5px;
}
```

If someone could explain to me how to achieve this I would very much appreciate it. Sorry if this is poorly worded .

Comment: Please also include the HTML code to match so we can better understand

Comment: It is not exactly clear what is not being resized. I suggest adding HTML code (if any) and/or a screenshot of a page when in default and resized view.

Generally, you should avoid using HTML tables for any other content or layout except data to be presented in a table (like in a spreadsheet).

I strongly suggest checking out Boostrap (since its easiest) https://getbootstrap.com 

Ping me if you update the question.